# need to display a drop down menu in the userform in VBA. The data to be displayed is stored in a table in a sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table, stored in a worksheet. I need to display the data of this table (only the first column) in a listbox in a User-form. Can anyone suggest me a way to do it ??? Thanks in advance . :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Focused on your combo box in the form designer by clicking on it, then look for a property in the properties explorer named 'row source'. Supply an appropriate cell range , e.g. Sheet2!A1:A20, or A:A for the entire A column, ....

Comment: Thanks very much. I need to pass the range as dynamic. what is to be done in that case?

Comment: Rachit, Most of the properties presented in the properties explorer are also available for access/setting through vba in the form of dot notation albeit usually through some obscure convoluted string of relations. This particular property seems fairly simple to set. Just set the [sheetName].[comboboxName].RowSource accessor to a cell range address accessor, like the following:

`Sheet1.Combobox1.RowSource = Sheet2.Range("A:A").Address`

Comment: Excuse me. In my last example, I accessed Combobox1 through Sheet1.Combobox1.... The right way to access a combobox in a userform is to go through the UserForm object, in my example that would be `UserForm1.Combobox1.RowSource = ...`.